# What is cryptic command for adding Excess Bagagge (chargeable SSR Element required) and issue EMD in Amadeus GDS

Tags: gds

I am trying to make scenario where I want to add Excess Baggage chargeable in PNE for 1 pax 1 segment in Amadeus GDS and generate EMD for the same. I read a couple of sites but they mostly shows steps to issue EMD instead of adding chargeable SSR then EMD.

Comment: Is this question complete? It looks like you've posted half a sentence and given up. In any case, I'm not sure that the intricacies of Amadeus really constitute a travel question.

Comment: sorry for that. Here is complete:

 I read couple of sites but all of mostly shows steps to issue EMD instead of adding chargeable SSR then EMD

Comment: I have updated the post for you Dashang - be aware you can edit your post.

Comment: To those voting to close, [GDS questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gds) have historically been on topic here, though few members here have the expertise to answer them. The OP may well get a better or faster answer at a forum specifically for travel agents.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the command, it is just for amadeus and different airlines has different format, its :

SRXBAG

ex: SRXBAG-TTL15KG1PC/S2

*// S2 is Segment*

Answer (score 0):

EXBG could be the command for excess baggage in Amadeus or search it along with fare if it exists as ancillary service and add to your flight segments and then issue an EMD against it!